# How to get callback from Room Database android Kotlin

Tags: android, database, kotlin

I want to get just row count as Int value from room database, 
not from initialized `LiveData` such as `livedata.value?.size`

**Dao class**

```
 @Dao 
interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User")
    fun getUserCount(): Int
 }
```

**Repository class**

```
class MyRepository(private val myDao: MyDao) {    
    fun getUserCount() = myDao.getUserCount()
}
```

**ViewModel class**

```
class MyViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    fun getUserCount() = myRepository.getUserCount()
}
```

This is what I want. But as you know we need to access room database at background thread, not at mainthread

so I changed the code like [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#8)

**Dao class**

```
 @Dao 
interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User")
    suspend fun getUserCount(): Int
 }
```

**Repository class**

```
class MyRepository(private val myDao: MyDao) {    
    suspend fun getUserCount() = myDao.getUserCount()
}
```

**ViewModel class**

```
class MyViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    fun getUserCount() = viewModelScope.launch {
            myRepository.getUserCount()
    }
}
```

if row count is 1, How can I get "1" as callback?

Comment: I'm not sure. But you might put result of myRepository.getUserCount() in variable and then use it in current launch to call some function.

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNT

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(column_name or primary key column name) from table_name ")
fun getCount(): Long
```

call `getCount()` from repository

Comment: Locat says "Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time."

Comment: add `suspend` keyword in `getCount` then call from `launch` block